# Android admob view set centered independent of orientation

Tags: android, admob

I'm having trouble setting right position of ads from admob. I've set a special layout for this ads

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/main_layout_ads"> 
</LinearLayout>
```

and defined ads as follows

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_UNIT_ID);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_ads);
adView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout.addView(adView, 0);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

The problem arises when I set a real device (HTC wildfire) and change orientation. All app changes accordingly, but ad remains on top left, instead of beign on top center as I desire.

Anyone can give me any clue about how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing/adding gravity="horizontal"

OR

Try putting the AdMob view into a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout.
In this example, the AdMob view is added dinamically by the code. It worked for me!

```
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad_layout_blank); // this is the RelativeLayout
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(adView, layoutParams);
        layout.invalidate();
```

XML layout:

```
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/ad_layout_blank"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Comment: a thousand thanks man. It worked in a right way. Don't know really why relative layout do the work and linearlayout not, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

So you know, the problem was that you set the layout_gravity on the LinearLayout, and the gravity on the AdView.

The difference is that layout_gravity is for the view itself inside its parent, and gravity is for children elements within the layout.

In summary, if you used gravity="center_horizontal" for the LinearLayout or gave the AdView LinearLayout.LayoutParams and set the gravity of the layout params to center_horizontal (equivalent to layout_gravity in XML) for the AdView, either would have worked. But ya got them both backwards.

Hope that made sense- you don't need a relative layout to center something.